# Release configuration for Ionic project, similar to flavours in Android studio

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Been looking into this without any luck. I understand that we can pass configuration to Ionic projects via the `config.xml` file. But I want to have different configuration for development and release builds.

Does anyone know about how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach that using the `hooks` to update a configuration file based on the specific environment you are building for.

You use a configuration variable when executing the cmd as the indicator of the environment.

`config_target=qa cordova build --release android ios`

then in the hook, check for the variable

`var config_target = process.env.config_target || "local"; // default to local`

http://www.kdmooreconsulting.com/blogs/build-a-cordova-hook-to-setup-environment-specific-constants/

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I'll try this out, Although I wish it were simpler, like having another config file that we can pass to the build command or something similar...

Comment: figured out a simpler approach. I can have a script that can swap out the config.xml file for another build specific config file and then build the project. of course that doesn't give the full benefits of Gradle flavours (mainly merging), but still simpler than working with hooks.

Comment: Hi Mahesh. It would be helpful if could you create a gist for the solution that worked for you. Thanks.