# How to integrate two or more google-services.json file in one project using ionic v3

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making a project in ionic v3. I need to integrate one or more fcm project for push notification.

Description:

project name is `example`

package id is `com.example.in`

Then I create two fcm project using two different user account using same package id and same project name.

Now I need to integrate that two fcm project in my app. How can I implement that?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can you share some code or what you have done and where you are stuck? With these information people in the community will be able to understand the problem and help. Thanks.

Comment: @vmorusu i need to integrate one or more fcm project in my application for push notification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent the entire day today to figure out the same challenge. I am surprised, a seemingly very common challenge, is not addressed on the web yet (or I was using wrong terminology in my search). Anyway, this is what worked for me (tested in browser):

**Disclaimer**: *I did it only for Android, you need to add to my steps below to include iOS (which I believe should follow the same)*

1. create the following files and directories in your project (these are the source files where configurations for both Firebase projects are hardcoded. config.xml needs to be replaced because of the different package name):
2. leveraging ionic hooks, create the file file `build-before.js` which contains the following script:

   ```js
   module.exports = function(ctx) {
     console.log(ctx);
     var fs = require("fs");
     var xmlConfig = "config.xml"

     if (ctx.build.configuration == 'production') {
       var srcfile = "src/production/google-services.json";
       var destfile = "google-services.json";
       var srcConfigfile = "src/production/config.xml";
       var destConfigfile = "config.xml";
       console.log("copying " + srcfile + " to " + destfile);
       fs.createReadStream(srcConfigfile).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destConfigfile));
       fs.createReadStream(srcfile).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destfile));


     } else {
       console.log("TARGET environment variable is not set.  Using default values.");

       var srcfile = "src/development/google-services.json";
       var destfile = "google-services.json";
       var srcConfigfile = "src/development/config.xml";
       var destConfigfile = "config.xml";
       console.log("copying " + srcfile + " to " + destfile);
       fs.createReadStream(srcConfigfile).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destConfigfile));
       fs.createReadStream(srcfile).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destfile));
     }
   }
   ```
3. in file `ionic.config.json` add the following:

   `"hooks": {
   "build:before": "./scripts/build-before.js"
   }`
4. Test with the following commands:

   `$ ionic cordova build android --prod`
   `$ ionic cordova build android`
   `$ ionic serve --prod`
   `$ ionic serve`

**Helpful refs**

- https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/
- [Cordova hook and access to build settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47236115/cordova-hook-and-access-to-build-settings)
- https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuration
- http://www.kdmooreconsulting.com/blogs/build-a-cordova-hook-to-setup-environment-specific-constants/
- http://intown.biz/2014/05/13/build-configurations-in-cordova-using-hooks/
- [Release configuration for Ionic project, similar to flavours in Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507199/release-configuration-for-ionic-project-similar-to-flavours-in-android-studio)
- [Cordova: What does PACKAGE_NAME in android.json mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020161/cordova-what-does-package-name-in-android-json-mean)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but needed the Google Plist to run on Ionic Appflow as well as local configurations.   For a solution that works for a Mono Repo, Appflow, and multiple environments do the following

Create a folder structure that contains your environments, for us it was

```
configs/develop
--> google-services.json & GoogleService-Info.plist
configs / qa
--> google-services.json & GoogleService-Info.plist
configs / staging
--> google-services.json & GoogleService-Info.plist
configs / production
--> google-services.json & GoogleService-Info.plist
```

Create a pre-build-config.js script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require("fs");
const [, , ...args] = process.argv
const configArg = args;

if (configArg.toString() == 'develop') {
    console.log('Pre-build - Configuring Android:', configArg);
    var srcfileAndroid = 'configs/' + configArg + '/google-services.json';
    var destfileAndroid = "projects/startup-wars-app/android/app/google-services.json";

    console.log("copying " + srcfileAndroid + " to " + destfileAndroid);
    fs.createReadStream(srcfileAndroid).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destfileAndroid));

    console.log('Pre-build - Configuring iOS:', configArg);
    var srcfileiOS = 'configs/' + configArg + '/GoogleService-Info.plist';
    var destfileiOS = "projects/startup-wars-app/ios/app/GoogleService-Info.plist";

    console.log("copying " + srcfileiOS + " to " + destfileiOS);
    fs.createReadStream(srcfileiOS).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destfileiOS));

} else {
    console.error("TARGET environment variable is not set.  Cannot set Firebase Config with Arg:", configArg);
}
```

Don't forget to
`chmod +x pre-build-config.js`

And on your gitignore

```
/projects/startup-wars-app/ios/app/GoogleService-Info.plist
/projects/startup-wars-app/android/app/google-services.json
```

Now create a cleanup script to remove the files that get moved into your Ionic application.  This will prevent confusion and throw an error on build step if you are missing the correct file

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require("fs");
var srcfileAndroid = "projects/startup-wars-app/android/app/google-services.json";
var srcfileiOS = "projects/startup-wars-app/ios/app/GoogleService-Info.plist";

console.log('After build cleanup of dynamic config files:');
try {
    fs.unlinkSync(srcfileAndroid);
    fs.unlinkSync(srcfileiOS);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

From Package.json, use npm hooks to call your pre-build and cleanup scripts

```
"prebuild:app:develop": "./pre-build-config.js develop",
"build:app:develop": "npm run check-imports && ng build --project startup-wars-app",
"postbuild:app:qa": "./after-build-cleanup.js",
```

And that's it - this should cover you for both iOS and Android.

NOTE: The pathing will be different if you're not using a mono repo, but besides that, it's the exact same.